# Krishn-Kaliya Story ReTold

Tags: history, non-hindu

Is Hercules & Hydra Just ReTold Krishn-Kaliya Story ?

Came across some Indian writers who posited the theory that the story of Hercules & Hydra is a myth stolen from Hinduism and adapted to another culture over centuries.

Which was new info for me I guess. Heard the Kaliya-Daman stories for so many years but didn’t make thr connection.

In Hinduism religious texts, is there any accurate/precise textual proof of this ? Or is just conjecture/speculation. Seems legit but not sure. Thx

Edit : Plz of course feel free to delete or close this question if is opinion-based. Thx

Comment: The Krishn-kaliya leela is given in Srimad Bhagavatha purana (16th Chapter 10th Canto ). Also commenting on other mythological stories seems illogical in this site

Comment: @Shashaank I don’t know, illogical or not, but if it’s an unacceptable topic then mods will close it soon, I assume ? I’m ok with that if they close it, no worries :)